# Corporate VPN blocking websockets

Tags: networking, vpn, nginx, jupyter-notebook

I have a server at work that I login into to use jupyter notebooks for data science projects. This has been working for years both when connected to the campus wifi or remotely over VPN. Now after some network upgrades I can still connect on campus wifi, but over VPN I get `WebSocket connection to 'ws://server.internal/notebook/api/kernels/af23e3bf-65a7-47d4-8ad0-1afce22997f6/channels?session_id=5d17ad5ef8374ba4bff8f10d0e1ba3e4' failed:` errors in the console leading to an error window saying `Connection failed A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.`

I launch the notebook process with `jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=/data2 --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8889`

and connect to the notebook server with nginx and the config is

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/server.internal/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name server.internal;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
        }

        location /notebook {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8889;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_read_timeout 86400;
                client_max_body_size 100m;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/server_err.log debug;
        }
```

In my nginx log I'll see a few errors like

```
2021/06/08 14:22:17 [error] 2258#2258: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.22.124.52, server: server.internal, request: "GET /notebook/api/sessions?_=1623089993100 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8889/notebook/api/sessions?_=1623089993100", host: "server.internal", referrer: "http://server.internal/notebook/tree/helen_mixed_infection/notebooks"
```

I don't get any errors in my jupyter logs so I think this is a network issue, but want to know if there's a way around it.

Comment: Can you try changing the proxy backend URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8889`?

Comment: What "network upgrades" are you referring to? Did you change something on your local system or network? Did your company's IT stuff change change something? Then you might want to ask them for help.

Comment: It was company IT, but they are not helpful at all

Comment: @user1686 I assumed you meant to change it in my nginx config. I tried this but no difference.

Comment: Yes, and can you also change the Jupyter command to listen on 127.0.0.1 as well? (Originally I was thinking of the "localhost is ::1" issue, but also a loopback listener is slightly more likely to work with firewalls on your PC than a wildcard listener, regardless of version).

Comment: You will have to have your IT Administrators debug the situation, we don't know anything about your network infrastructure, we will be unable to diagnose the reason something is blocked on a network we know nothing about.  Since you don't have elevated permissions or the ability to make the required changes yourself you are forced to asked your IT Administrator for assistance.

Comment: @user1686, I still get the same issue with changing the jupyter command to 127.0.0.1